# Possible conjugations of "venir de + infinitive"

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conjugaison

Which of the following are used in practice, or make sense, even if they are rare or literary?

If all of them may be used, do they all mean different things, even if the differences are subtle, or are some of them in fact equivalent?

I've tried to offer my best attempt at translations that show the (sometimes subtle) differences, the way I think they are, but it seems to me that at least some of them must be functionally equivalent, for example 3 and 8, or 5 and 10.

But I'm very unsure about many of them, so perhaps someone with a better grasp of French tenses and aspects may help make sense of them.

1. Il vient de pleuvoir (It just rained)
2. Il venait de pleuvoir (It had just been raining)
3. Il vint de pleuvoir (It had just rained)
4. Il viendra de pleuvoir (It will just be raining)
5. Il viendrait de pleuvoir (It would have just rained)
6. Il est venu de pleuvoir (It has just rained)
7. Il était venu de pleuvoir (It has just been raining)
8. Il fut venu de pleuvoir (It had just rained)
9. Il sera venu de pleuvoir (It will have just rained)
10. Il serait venu de pleuvoir (It would have just rained)

Comment: Your question is too vague. *Venir de+ inf* (recent past) will not be used with any tense, the difference between one tense or another can at times be straightforward but at others very subtle, the use of one tense or another depends on the context. Your question needs to be more detailed, for example give a sentence with a precise context and if you are using the wrong tense or there's an error in your sentence we can tell you and explain. **Give more details**. Please visit the [Help centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on how to ask questions.

Comment: @None If I could give a precise context for all 10 sentences, I would already have my answer, so I honestly don't see how I could make my question more precise. Also, if "venir de+inf will not be used with any tense" is true, then that answers my question, as that means "only #1 is used, none of the others are ever used".

Comment: Not only #1 can be used. To tell you which tenses can be used and which can't requires to make up sentences in different contexts. What you are asking is a lecture on *venir de* and this is not the point of FL.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to give me 10 sentences, I'm just asking "can it be done?" (a simple yes/no) and "would they all be different", which would at most require a few words of explanation (in case the answer is no). For example: "Yes, all ten are possible, but #4 and #9 both mean 'It will have just ...', ...."

Comment: I would think this sort of question is a perfect candidate for something like Google NGram search.

Comment: The problem with searching for an answer, whether on NGram or otherwise, is that you get a lot of results for "venir de + something that's not an infinitive"

Comment: **venir de** is an idiom that means: **to have just done something**. Il vient de manger. = He has just eaten. I will, therefore, let you draw your own conclusions. Clue: the tenses with an auxiliary do not work.

Comment: @Lambie Indeed, but I'm just wandering if the past conditional would not work. Wouldn't something like *Il serait venu de manger que ça ne m'aurait pas étonné.* work? Not sure, got to let it brew for a while.

Comment: @S.T.Veje There are lots of online grammar sites on French grammar that you can look at. Please look at the help centre and see what sorts of questions are expected on FL. You are not new to SE, so be aware that a close reason on French Language is "This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @None  Sure, it works: Had he just eaten that would not have surprised me. But it's pushing it, right? I should go through the list more carefully. Il est et fut venu certainly don't work. I think the OP needs first to realize what the idiom actually means then, s/he would not have asked the question.

Comment: I've tried to be more specific, though I'm unsure if it helps. And yes, I know what the idiom means.

Comment: Il vient de pleuvoir is It has just rained. It just rained in English is non-standard but would be the same thing Il vient de pleuvoir in French.  Il est venu and sera venu de pleuvoir don't exist. The English has just been raining, like all present continuous verbs in English are usually just present in French: He's been spending huge amounts recently. Il dépense des quantités énormes recemment.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten that French expresses the continuous aspect (if at all) with "être en train de". I need to take that into account, once I'm less tired and able to think clearly about it.

Comment: No, that's wrong. It has been raining a lot recently. is merely: Il pleut beaucoup recemment. You don't translate every continuous with être en train de. You only do that when there is an ambiguity in the French.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "if at all"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Il vient de pleuvoir* (It just rained) ✔
*Il venait de pleuvoir* (It had just been raining) ✔
*<s>Il vint de pleuvoir</s>* (It had just rained) ✘
*Il viendra de pleuvoir* (It will just be raining) ✔ (rare)
*Il viendrait de pleuvoir* (It would have just rained) ✔ (rare)
*<s>Il est venu de pleuvoir</s>* (It has just rained) ✘
*<s>Il était venu de pleuvoir</s>* (It has just been raining) ✘
*<s>Il fut venu de pleuvoir</s>* (It had just rained) ✘
*<s>Il sera venu de pleuvoir</s>* (It will have just rained) ✘
*<s>Il serait venu de pleuvoir</s>* (It would have just rained) ✘

See *[De la défectivité de aller et de venir dans les périphrases d’ultériorité (il va pleuvoir) et d’antériorité (il vient de pleuvoir) proches à l’indicatif](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304542237_De_la_defectivite_de_aller_et_de_venir_dans_les_periphrases_d%27ulteriorite_il_va_pleuvoir_et_d%27anteriorite_il_vient_de_pleuvoir_proches_a_l%27indicatif)*, Jacques Bres, 2015.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. The link answers my question perfectly.